# How to update the first row records for each stock in a DolphinDB table?

Tags: dolphindb

I'd like to update the first price record for each stock without changing other records. The problem is I cannot find an efficient way to set the conditions concisely as a stock id column contains various stocks. Any suggestions on function use?

btw I've checked similar questions, but it seems the answers do not apply to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use function`iif` together with `rowNo` so you can update the given information easily:

```
pp = table(`a`a`a`b`b`c`c`c`c as id, 1..9 as price)
update pp set price = iif(rowNo(price)==0,0,price) context by id
```

[image]